# Depth estimation using structured light pattern

Tags: python

I have been trying to generate a disparity image using OpenCV's block matching algorithm, for the start, using reference and query image.
I get only garbage image even using the two enclosed images.

My question is: what am I missing ?
If rectification is needed - how can this be done for camera+projector system ?

[image: reference image]
[image: query image]

Code that I used:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

imgRef = cv2.imread("a0.png", 0)
imgQer = cv2.imread("a1.png", 0)

stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=128, blockSize=25)
stereo.setMinDisparity(0)

disparity_map = stereo.compute(imgRef, imgQer)
disparity_map[disparity_map<0]=0

disparity_map = (disparity_map.astype(np.float32) - np.min(disparity_map)) / (np.max(disparity_map) - np.min(disparity_map)) * 255.0
cv2.imwrite("out.png", disparity_map.astype(np.uint8))
```